# Hide Unistall button by overriding template file in component `sw-extension-card-base`

Tags: shopware6

I want to remove the uninstall link from the shopware My Extension page. The component is registered in file `vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-extension/component/sw-extension-card-base/index.js` as below

```
import template from './sw-extension-card-base.html.twig';
import './sw-extension-card-base.scss';

const { Component, Utils, Filter } = Shopware;

/**
 * @package merchant-services
 * @private
 */
Component.register('sw-extension-card-base', {
    template,

    inheritAttrs: false,

    inject: ['shopwareExtensionService', 'extensionStoreActionService', 'cacheApiService'],

    mixins: ['sw-extension-error'],

    props: {
        extension: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
```

I tried to override the component and adding a new template file as below

```
import template from './sw-extension-card-base.html.twig';
const { Component} = Shopware;

/**
 * @package merchant-services
 * @private
 */
Component.override('sw-extension-card-base', {
    template
});`

However the override is not working. I also observed the component is extended in other components

`import template from '../sw-extension-permissions-details-modal/sw-extension-permissions-details-modal.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

/**
 * @package merchant-services
 * @private
 */
Component.extend('sw-self-maintained-extension-card', 'sw-extension-card-base', {
    template,

    mixins: ['sw-extension-error'],

    props: {
        extension: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
```

Can someone guide on how to override this component and hide unistall link

Comment: Why did you duplicate your question? Even unsure why you would want to do this - You would probably need to change the core code of Shopaware. The current code posted has nothing to do with the issue at hand